How to create a chart using Data Nitro in Excel
I am currently using DataNitro in Excel.
I have a dataframe with a time series of prices (actual vs predicted) that I would like to plot (via python code) using Data Nitro add-in in excel (with a specific position on the active sheet with a specific dimension).
I would like to plot a multiple bar chart for each date (like below), and also specify the placement of the chart within the sheet and the dimensions/size of the chart (using x and y axes arguments, if any).
How do I achieve this?



Data Nitro isn't used to create Excel Charts. If want to do this then its Openpyxl, Xlwings or Win32com see those modules for how to. Not sure how Data Nitro applies here... Though of course this is not a site for writing your code, this is a site where you have written your code and have a question(s) about the code.
